# Construct customized Restlet login web page

Tags: java, authentication, restlet

I have implemented login for my Restlet server that uses ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC over HTTPS and references a database table of users with salted passwords.  The relevant code snippet:

```
ChallengeAuthenticator challAuthn = new ChallengeAuthenticator(getContext.createChildContext, ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "Enter your id and password");
SecretVerifier mySecretVerifier = new MySecretVerifier();
challAuthn.setVerifier(mySecretVerifier);
```

It works, but does not look very professional, and shows the user a screen like this:

[image: Simple Default Login]

I would like instead to show the user a web page that I could customize with a graphic theme, for example, something like this:

[image: Example of Customized Login]

Any help to reduce my ignorance is welcome!

Comment: Alternately, it would be helpful if someone could point me to web service that **uses Restlet** and **has a login page** and **is open source** so I could use their code as an example.

Comment: My (possibly flawed) understanding is :  
  
1: When a client browser first tries to connect, the request will not have credentials.  
  
2: My server can see the lack of credentials, and redirect them to a login page.  
  
3: On the login page the user enters their user id and password.  
  
4: My server can verify that the user id and password are correct.  

5: At this point my server should tell the client to use these credentials for requests in the remainder of the session.  
        **And telling the client is the part I do not know how to do.**